# Jenkins - Trigger parameterized build on other dependent project,SVN-Revert

Tags: svn, jenkins, triggers, rollback, parameterized

How I can handle dependency of projects?
For example I Have 3 projects(Jenkins Jobs) A,B,C.

A contains asp.net website

B contains database

C contains service

I want to deploy A,B,C if and only if all the three projects builds successfully.If one fails all builds should rollback.
If there is any change in one of three, all 3 should build.